# GCC x64 on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, mingw

I tried installing CygWin64, but I cannot find any executables to build my code with in the C:\cygwin64 directory created.

I tried Win-Builds but the setup doesn't load with any mirror I give it. It tries to connect 3 times then aborts.

I tried MinGW-W64-Builds, but I cannot figure out how to install it. I can see a .sh file there, but I believe that is for Linux, so I do not know why because it says it is for Windows

Is there even a way to use 64-bit GCC on Windows? I am trying to tie it to a Code::Blocks IDE as that one only comes with the 32-bit version of MinGW.

Comment: Did you use the Cygwin setup.exe?  Did you remember to check the GCC 64-bit compiler collecton?

Comment: MSYS2 has x64 GCC in its package manager. I suggest avoiding Cygwin, unless you know what it is and actually need the POSIX emulation it offers.

Comment: There was a comment here about MSYS2 that was deleted for some reason. I installed everything, added the compiler to Code::Blocks, set it as default but it still runs with its default MinGW compiler no matter what I do. Every file is set correctly

Comment: @NiInThTrCo I deleted it to repost it with a suggestion to avoid Cygwin. *"still runs with its default MinGW compiler"* Can you post screenshots of CB compiler settings, and explain why do you think it still runs the old compiler?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mVOeJPX Here is some screenshots. I tried setting a compiler I do not have as default and I get the same result, making me think that it just uses the default one no matter what

Comment: @NiInThTrCo It's been a while since I used CB, so I don't remember how to select the default compiler. The easy option is change the settings of "GNU GCC Compiler" (rather than "GNU GCC x64 Compiler"), which seems to be the default compiler. CB isn't particularly smart, it shouldn't care if you gave it an x32 or x64 compiler.

Comment: Yup, that did it, it's not a 64-bit executable! If you want to post an answer here, I'll accept it for others to see. Thanks bro

Comment: @NiInThTrCo What's not 64-bit executable, the compiler? It should be... *"Thanks bro"* You're welcome! *"If you want to post an answer"* I'll pass, you can post one yourself if you want to.

Comment: I meant to say it's now a 64-bit executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out out the MinGW-w64 + GCC personal build at http://winlibs.com/.
No installation required, just unzip.
Examples on how to use are on the site, including on how to integrate with Code::Blocks IDE.